# AWS CodeDeploy deployment failed at event ApplicationStop

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I am trying to set up auto-deployment from GitHub to AWS, using EC2.
I set Role with CodeDeployServiceRole [auto policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtEhg.png)

After following the Tutorial: Use AWS CodeDeploy to Deploy an Application from GitHub, my deployment [fails at the ApplicationStop event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hliwv.png), after trying for couple of minutes with error code HEALTH_CONSTRAINT. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the issue/where to look.

Comment: do you have old deployments before that failure?
also, are you defining that step in your appspec yaml file or leaving the default ?

Comment: Also, you can find the logs of CodeDeploy agent on the server in ` /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent`

Comment: It would be great if OP could update us on how and if they managed to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 13):

These are few hints of how you can navigate your way

- Logs as mentioned in comments in `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent`
- As AWS support recommend you can add for one time `--ignore-application-stop-failures`  so it will skip that step in case it failed last time and see، because the application stop Lifecycle event uses the `appspec` file from the last successful build so if that one is corrupted somehow this step will fail in the following builds
- (not recommended) you can delete the file, that CodeDeploy uses to keep track of the previous successful deployment in the following path `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-instructions/`

Comment: Where do we set up that file

Comment: which file you mean?

Answer (score 7):

Check the latest logs at `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent`

If your deployment is failing at `ApplicationStop` event, then most likely the issue is your EC2 instance does not have the necessary permissions to get the artifacts from S3 bucket.

1. Your EC2 instance must have an IAM role attached which gives it enough permissions to download the artifacts from S3 bucket
2. Your EC2 must be **started with** an IAM role. So you may have to reboot your instance after attaching the role to it.

From your configuration, looks like you have provided permissions to `CodeDeploy` to perform certain actions on your EC2. You may want to check if your EC2 also has the necessary permissions to download packages from S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason for this error is that the CodeDeploy Service is not running on your machine. On Windows machines, Code Deploy Service terminates sometimes, and as a result, the deployment is not downloaded on the machine. Nothing appears in the logs either.
Run services.msc and check the code deploy agent service. If it is not running, start it and retry the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by solving codedeploy-agent that wasn't working on my EC2 instance.

```
sudo service {httpd/apache2} status
```

Something might have cause the agent not to run properly

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You also need to make sure that your EC2 instance has code-deploy-agent installed.

Follow the below aws guide. It worked for me.

[AWS guide to install code agent in linux server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-linux.html)

Check if the codedeploy-agent is running.

`sudo service codedeploy-agent status`

if not running then use below command to run

`sudo service codedeploy-agent start`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aws **Windows** server, check the logs at :

```
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\log\codedeploy-agent-log.txt
```

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html#deployments-view-logs-instance)

To check if the [codedeployagent running in windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-verify.html). Open powersheel command window and run these command.

```
powershell.exe -Command Get-Service -Name codedeployagent
```

Better to stop and start again.

```
powershell.exe -Command Stop-Service -Name codedeployagent
powershell.exe -Command Start-Service -Name codedeployagent
```

Or Restarting also works

`powershell.exe -Command Restart-Service -Name codedeployagent`

For me I had to [uninstall the codedeployagent on windows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-uninstall.html) by uninstalling and deleting old files of codedeploy.

Run the below command in powershell one by one to uninstall.

```
wmic

product where name="CodeDeploy Host Agent" call uninstall /nointeractive

exit
```

After this delete the codedeploy folder at this location.

```
C:\ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/
```

Now install [`codedeployagent on windows`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-windows.html).

Start the codedeployagent again.

```
powershell.exe -Command Start-Service -Name codedeployagent
```